# How to loop through dictionary to get both frequency of words and symbols?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have set up a function that finds the frequency of the number of times words appear in a text file, but the frequency is wrong for a couple of words because the function is not separating words from symbols like "happy,".

I have already tried to use the split function to split it with every "," and every "." but that does not work, I am also not allowed to import anything into the function as the professor does not want us to.

The code belows turns the text file into a dictionary and then uses the word or symbol as the key and the frequency as the value.

```
def getTokensFreq(file):
    dict = {}
    with open(file, 'r') as text:
        wholetext = text.read().split()
        for word in wholetext:
            if word in dict:
                dict[word] += 1
            else:
                dict[word] = 1
    return dict
```

We are using the text file with the name of "f". This what is inside the file.

`I felt happy because I saw the others were happy and because I knew I should feel happy, but I was not really happy.`

The desired results is this where both words and symbols are counted.

`{'i': 5, 'felt': 1, 'happy': 4, 'because': 2, 'saw': 1,
'the': 1, 'others': 1, 'were': 1, 'and': 1, 'knew': 1, 'should': 1,
'feel': 1, ',': 1, 'but': 1, 'was': 1, 'not': 1, 'really': 1, '.': 1}`

This is what I am getting, where some words and symbols are counted as a separate word

> {'I': 5, 'felt': 1, 'happy': 2, 'because': 2, 'saw': 1, 'the': 1, 'others': 1, 'were': 1, 'and': 1, 'knew': 1, 'should': 1, 'feel': 1, 'happy,': 1, 'but': 1, 'was': 1, 'not': 1, 'really': 1, 'happy.': 1}

Comment: Use a regular expression...

Comment: Also, unless I am missing some part of your question, your desired output doesn't seem to be counting 'I', 'happy', etc. Is that just by mistake or are there more filter criteria?

Comment: import the string module and then you can remove punctuation without regex. whole_text = text.read().strip()

Then text_list = whole_text.split()

Comment: If you can't import the `re` module you can test each character of your string if it is a letter with `c.isalpha()` where c is the character. Based on that you can create a function to split words (alphas only) from other characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how to generate your desired frequency dictionary for one sentence. To do for the whole file, just call this code for each line to update the content of your dictionary.

```py
# init vars
f = "I felt happy because I saw the others were happy and because I knew I should feel happy, but I was not really happy."
d = {}

# count punctuation chars
d['.'] = f.count('.')
d[','] = f.count(',')

# remove . and , 
for word in f.replace(',', '').replace('.','').split(' '):
    if word not in d.keys():
        d[word] = 1
    else: 
        d[word] += 1
```

Alternatively, you can use a mix of regex and list expressions, like the following:

```
import re

# filter words and symbols
words   = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9\s]+', '', f).split(' ')
symbols = re.sub('[A-Za-z0-9\s]+', ' ', f).strip().split(' ')

# count occurrences
count_words   = dict(zip(set(words),   [words.count(w) for w in set(words)]))
count_symbols = dict(zip(set(symbols), [symbols.count(s) for s in set(symbols)]))

# parse results in dict
d = count_symbols.copy()
d.update(count_words)
```

Output:

```
{',': 1,
 '.': 1,
 'I': 5,
 'and': 1,
 'because': 2,
 'but': 1,
 'feel': 1,
 'felt': 1,
 'happy': 4,
 'knew': 1,
 'not': 1,
 'others': 1,
 'really': 1,
 'saw': 1,
 'should': 1,
 'the': 1,
 'was': 1,
 'were': 1}
```

Running the previous 2 approaches a 1000x times using a loop and capturing the run-times, proves that the second approach is **faster** than the first approach.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is firstly replace all symbols into a space and then split by space. We will need a little help from regular expression.

```
import re

a = 'I felt happy because I saw the others were happy and because I knew I should feel happy, but I was not really happy.'

b =  re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', ' ', a)
print(b)
wholetext = b.split(' ')
print(wholetext)
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is similar to Verse's but it also takes makes an array of the symbols in the sentence. Afterwards, you can use the for loop and the dictionary to determine the counts.

```
import re

a = 'I felt happy because I saw the others were happy and because I knew I should feel happy, but I was not really happy.'

b =  re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9\s]+', ' ', a)
print(b)
wholetext = b.split(' ')
print(wholetext)
c = re.sub('[A-Za-z0-9\s]+', ' ', a)
symbols = c.strip().split(' ')
print(symbols)

# do the for loop stuff you did in your question but with wholetext and symbols
```

Oh, I missed that you couldn't import anything :(